# Storing a function pointer taking generic parameter slice in struct

Tags: rust

I'm in a situation where I need to store away a function that implements a trait into a struct. Here is some reduced code

```
struct Node<T>{
    compute_func: Box<dyn Fn(&[T]) -> T>
}

impl<T: Debug + 'static> OtherHoldingStruct<T> {
pub fn create_node<F: Fn(&[T]->T>(..., _compute_func: F) {
    Node {
         compute_function: Box::new(_compute_func),
//~~~~ the parameter type `impl Fn(&[T]) -> T` may not live long enough
//~~~~  ...so that the type `impl Fn(&[T]) -> T` will meet its required lifetime bounds rustc(E0310)

    }
}
```

What I gather is that since I'm trying to accept a function type that takes a reference to a slice, the compiler is trying to create some assurances around how the lifetime of the reference to the slice will behave. What i'm not sure of is how to give it that ?

I considered adding a lifetime to create_node

```
impl<T: Debug + 'static> OtherHoldingStruct<T> {
pub fn create_node<'a, F: Fn(&'a [T]->T>(..., _compute_func: F) {
    Node {
         compute_function: Box::new(_compute_func),
//~~~~ expected a `std::ops::Fn<(&[T],)>` closure, found `impl Fn(&'a [T]) -> T`
    }
}
```

which then seems to barf at not being able to match closures to the type.

Comment: Try with `pub fn create_node<F: Fn(&[T]->T + 'static>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the slice reference — it's a lifetime requirement on *the function type `F` itself.* If you're going to store the function, then the function itself must be able to live for `'static` (unless there's an explicitly permitted shorter lifetime).

The requirement actually in your code causing the compiler error appears because `dyn Fn` (or any other `dyn`) has an implicit `+ 'static` bound if you don't specify a different lifetime. Thus, the bounds for `F` in `create_node` are `Fn(&[T]) -> T` but the bounds for `compute_function` are `Fn(&[T]) -> T + 'static`, creating the error you saw.

The fix is to add a `'static` bound on `F`:

```rust
pub fn create_node<F: Fn(&[T]) -> T + 'static>(_compute_func: F) -> Node<T> {
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

This bound disallows passing, for example, a closure that captures a non-static reference, which *has* to be invalid anyway since `Node` could live indefinitely, unlike that reference.